# Picture is not coming up as background in Shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinyapps

I am struggling to put a `SVG` image as background of some `div` in `UI`. Below is my minimal `Shiny app` -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style = "height: 100px; width: 100px; background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg') no-repeat top left;")
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you see, the picture is not coming up as background.

Really appreciate for any pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the CSS property `background` instead of `background-image`. Moreover, the dimensions you set are too small for containing the image. Try:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style = "height: 392px; width: 472px; background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/1029/files/Freesample.svg) no-repeat top left;")
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```